# Legal term for not knowing details about the crime

Tags: phrase-requests, legalese

I can't remember the legal term for hmm... not knowing details about the crime.
I will explain on the example:

Let's say that we suspect that our friend is going to rob a bank. And he asks us "do you want to know what I'm going to do tonight?" And then we say 'no' because we want to be able to honestly tell the police "I don't know anything about it."

What's the legal term for that? It's pretty common in the movies and TV shows.

Comment: Probably best for http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *plausible deniability* ??

Comment: You could also be an *accessory* to the crime if you know and don't say something. http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/aiding-and-abetting-accessory.html

Comment: "Plausible deniability" is certainly the term in politics, but I'm not so sure about law.

Comment: @HotLicks I think we are going to see a lot of "plausible deniability" going on in the future months...

Comment: @Cascabel I think it will be implausible denial.

Comment: @Hank Please don't make me check 51 jurisdictions, but I doubt that simply knowing about a crime in advance of its commission could lead to a charge as an accessory. Probably not even aiding and abetting.

Comment: I'm not lawyer, but I do believe having knowledge of a crime and not reporting it does make you involved. I only shared what I found from research. The following is a post about specifically California https://www.wklaw.com/knowing-about-a-crime-and-not-saying-anything/

Comment: @Hank I'm not a lawyer either, but generally in the US there's no such thing as a thought crime (at least, not yet), which your cite confirms. Unless you're what's called a *mandated reporter* for things like child abuse, simply silently knowing about a crime is not a crime in itself. You can't take any action to aid a criminal, and you can't deny knowledge if authorities ask, although you don't have to talk to them.

Answer (score 3):

***Willful Blindness*** -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willful_blindness)

> *Willful blindness* (sometimes called ignorance of law, willful ignorance or contrived ignorance or Nelsonian knowledge) is a term used in law to describe a situation in which a person seeks to avoid civil or criminal liability for a wrongful act by intentionally keeping himself or herself unaware of facts that would render him or her liable.

Comment: Please include the relevant portion of text from the link.